# How to delineate these coloured mandals as different shapefiles using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image][image: ChittoorDistrict]

The image shown above is everything I have! Is there a way to make separate shapefiles for all the coloured palletts

Comment: You could contact the URL near the scale bar and see if they could email you the data if you ask *very* nicely. If they don't want to part with their data then your best bet is to georeference the image and heads-up digitize it. There appears to be a watermark which would make any type of automated classification frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The Polygonize tool will get you part of the way there (Raster > Conversion > Polygonize). The text and watermark will need to be cleaned up. 
Alternatively, look around online, there might be free shapefiles. For example - https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html# (though it is a 1.2GB download and includes data you dont need).

Comment: Fortunately, I found a new picture without watermark. Can you help me with that?